# System error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT and error 403 mongodb

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, http-status-code-403

I have code for a react website that I pulled from git from windows to a mac. All my code worked fine before, but now when I run the website, I can't even load it and get the following error. The page starts with an api fetch to the backend into mongoDB. I have the correct access to the database, since all my functions work when I test the backend using postman. The issue arises when my website tries to fetch data. Does anyone know what could be causing the issue? I have the proxy set up to localhost on which my backend runs in the client's package.json file too.

[image: console error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what happened, but I removed cors from the backend, put it back and now the frontend is connecting to the backend.